# Property Reader

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, properties

i have used Property Reader Method but getting the error - Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of `java.util.Properties.get(Object)` is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "java.util.Properties.get(Object)" is null
at org.automation.library.PropertyReader.elementLocatorReader(PropertyReader.java:25)
at org.webservices.testcase.TC_001_Homepage.startBrowser(TC_001_Homepage.java:26)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:969)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

```
public class PropertyReader {

    public static String applicationConfigReader(String key) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("./Configurations/ApplicationCOnfig.properties");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(fr);
        return prop.get(key).toString();
    }
    
    public static String elementLocatorReader(String key) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("./ElementLocator/Locator.properties");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(fr);
        return prop.get(key).toString();
    }
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()"
> because the return value of "java.util.Properties.get(Object)" is null

Comment: It isn’t clear what the question is. I guess the key passed to the method isn’t in the file, but we can’t see either the key or the contents of the file.